# ACL in linux-based samba shares

Tags: linux, samba, access-control-list

If I mount a samba share like this from a linux server using ACL in ext3...

`mount -t cifs //192.168.0.10/smbshare /mnt/smbshare -o user=root password=secret`

...and access the share with linux/smb-user smbuser. I have given smbuser write access to all catalogs, but when I write something to the share the owner becomes root (the user that mountet the share).

Is there any possibility to make smbuser the owner of the files/catalogs he creates even if the share is mountet by the root-user?

This case is supposed to work on a linux terminal server so many different users access the smb share (mountet by root).

Comment: I want to mount this in fstab - so this isn't inside a script that every runs when a user logs on.

Answer (score 1):

just add the the parameters `uid=smbuser,gid=<smbusergroup>` to your mount command and all files and directories will belong to smbuser.

Comment: But what do I do when smbuser2 writes something to the common share on the terminal server? (which then writes everything as smbuser)

Comment: as i understand this, this is different from what you asked first. what is your final goal or what other requirements do you have?